# Unable to find the exact dimension of an expression

Tags: syntax, broken-code

I have defined a variable called y, this contains a huge equation, but when I look for the dimension of y it shows 3. How come a single expression has dimensions of 3? It is supposed to be 1 right?

```
y=39.25 ω^2 (1.00519 Subscript[a,4][1]^2+1.00102 Subscript[a,4][2]^2+2.19056 Subscript[a,4][1] Subscript[a,4][3]-1.07645 Subscript[a,4][2] Subscript[a,4][3]+1.5 Subscript[a,4][3]^2+0.55507 Subscript[a,4][1] Subscript[a,4][4]+1.54742 Subscript[a,4][2] Subscript[a,4][4]+1.5 Subscript[a,4][4]^2);;
Dimensions[y]
```

Comment: Well, it is a product of three things. A one-dimensional list, of three elements.

Comment: `Dimensions` needs a full array as argument (see documentation) . If you apply it to a scalar surprising results like `Dimension[a+b] (* 2*) ` occur.

Comment: It is  a single expression right. Is it possible to make one expression with dimension 1

Comment: Yes, something like  `{a +b}`

Comment: Perhaps you would be interested in [`LeafCount`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html) which gives the total number of indivisible subexpressions. In this case, `78`

Comment: It gives me `{3}' also, but when I `FullSimplify` the expression for y, I get `{2}`.  Strange.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe what you are looking for is [`LeafCount`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeafCount.html). [`TreeForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TreeForm.html) is also useful for visualizing expressions.

```
TreeForm @ y
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of tensor analysis, a scalar has no dimensions at all. You can make your own function that reflects this:

```
arrayDimensions[x_?ArrayQ] := Dimensions[x]
arrayDimensions[x_] := {}
arrayDimensions[{1, 2}]
(* {2} *)
arrayDimensions[a + b]
(* {} *}
```